# Slow SELECT query over DBLink - Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to use to following query over an Oracle DBLink to retrieve some data from Oracle EBS to another system.

```
WITH 
        --Este CTE ira receber todos os fornecedores
 cteallvendors AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        asu.vendor_name,
        apv.vendor_id,
        ssa.address_line1,
        ssa.address_line2,
        ssa.address_line3,
        ssa.address_line4,
        ssa.city,
        ssa.state,
        ssa.global_attribute10
        || ''
        || ssa.global_attribute11
        || ''
        || ssa.global_attribute12 cnpj
    FROM
        apps.ap_suppliers@k2prd            asu
        LEFT JOIN apps.ap_vendors_v@k2prd            apv ON apv.vendor_id = asu.vendor_id
        LEFT JOIN apps.ap_supplier_sites_all@k2prd   ssa ON apv.vendor_id = ssa.vendor_id
                                                          AND asu.vendor_id = ssa.vendor_id
)
SELECT
    mmt.transaction_id,
    cffea.document_type     "TIPO_DOCUMENTO",
    rt.vendor_id            "NUMERO_FORNECEDOR",
    vendors.vendor_name     "NOME_FORNECEDOR",
    cfi.invoice_num         "NUMERO_NOTA",
    cfi.series              "SERIE",
    mp.organization_code    "OI",
    mmt.subinventory_code   "SUBINVENTARIO",
    msib.segment1           "CODIGO_ITEM",
    mmt.transaction_uom     "UOM",
    msib.description        "DESCRICAO",
    mmt.creation_date,
    rt.transaction_type
FROM
    apps.mtl_material_transactions@k2prd      mmt
    LEFT JOIN apps.rcv_transactions@k2prd               rt ON mmt.rcv_transaction_id = rt.transaction_id
    LEFT JOIN apps.cll_f189_invoice_lines@k2prd         cfil ON rt.organization_id = cfil.organization_id
                                                        AND rt.po_line_location_id = cfil.line_location_id
    LEFT JOIN apps.cll_f189_invoices@k2prd              cfi ON cfil.invoice_id = cfi.invoice_id
    LEFT JOIN apps.cll_f189_invoice_types@k2prd         cfit ON cfi.invoice_type_id = cfit.invoice_type_id
    LEFT JOIN apps.cll_f189_fiscal_entities_all@k2prd   cffea ON cfi.entity_id = cffea.entity_id
    LEFT JOIN apps.cll_f189_fiscal_operations@k2prd     cffo ON cfil.cfo_id = cffo.cfo_id
    LEFT JOIN cteallvendors                             vendors ON rt.vendor_id = vendors.vendor_id
    LEFT JOIN apps.mtl_parameters@k2prd                 mp ON mmt.organization_id = mp.organization_id
    LEFT JOIN apps.mtl_system_items_b@k2prd             msib ON msib.inventory_item_id = mmt.inventory_item_id
                                                    AND msib.organization_id = mmt.organization_id
    LEFT JOIN apps.mtl_transaction_types@k2prd          mtt ON mmt.transaction_type_id = mtt.transaction_type_id
WHERE
    nvl(mmt.attribute1, '0') = '0'
    AND ( ( rt.transaction_type = 'DELIVER'
            AND cfit.credit_debit_flag = 'D' )
          OR ( rt.transaction_type = 'RETURN TO RECEIVING'
               AND cfit.credit_debit_flag = 'C' ) )
    AND cffo.cfo_code IN (
        1101,
        2101,
        3101
    )
    AND upper(mtt.transaction_type_name) IN (
        'PO RECEIPT',
        'RETURN TO VENDOR'
    )
        ORDER BY
            transaction_id
```

But the execution times are horrible over DBLink.

It usually takes a few milliseconds to run it on the origin database (around 0.500 to one second when a data load is going, this is the usual time), but when i try to run it from the DBLink, it doesn't bring any results. I left it running for over an hour, other queries over the same DBLink work normally, also, other DBLinks work fine as well.

Could someone help me to solve this situation? Is the query poorly optimized or might be an infrastructure issue going on.

Comment: You need to run an explain plan and post the results here

Comment: Can you check the execution time of the query after applying the `/*+DRIVING_SITE*/` hint?

Comment: @Tejash, thanks, i will try.

Comment: @OldProgrammer, i can't post the results here because they contain information about our service providers and we can get into trouble if those get leaked. Sorry.

Comment: Can you paste the execution plan? Also more details on "origin db" will be helpful

Comment: Hi, is this a one time fetch of data with no plans to periodically do this? You are doing a lot of work over a database link. Have you considered doing all your work on the source database, k2prd, (e.g. create a view of your sql in k2prd), and then query the view in your destination database? Have you considered creating a table to store your results in k2prd and then bringing data over the database link?